# Proper way to deal with redundant function arguments

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose the following class hierarchy with a base class and some general case class that inherits from the base:

```
class BaseClass:
    def f(self, a, b):
        #do something
        pass

class GeneralCase(BaseClass):
    def f(self, a, b):
        BaseClass.f(self, a, b)
        #do something else
```

Now, suppose that we have a special case, in which (among others) one of the arguments of function `f` is predetermined and constant. One
way to implement this is to remove this argument from the argument list as follows:

```
class SpecialCase1(GeneralCase):
    def f(self, a):
```

Pro's: clean,   explicit

Con's: different method signature might cause problems when objects of different classes are used

Option 2: set default value and assert it is not changed

```
class SpecialCase2(GeneralCase):
    def f(self, a, b=PREDEFINED_VALUE):
        assert b == PREDEFINED_VALUE
        GeneralCase.f(self, a, PREDEFINED_VALUE)
```

Pro's: same signature

Con's: confusing interface: "Why do we have parameter b? what happens if I change it?"

What approach would you preffer and why?

Comment: There is a third option: Make `get_b` a method and let subclasses override it, so you don't need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: is this a typo assert p == PREDEFINED_VALUE and should be assert b = PREDEFINED_VALUE ?

Comment: Both approaches suck. It shouldn't be a subtype at all.

Comment: If you check the value don't you go on the same problems (even worst) that for the first solution ?

Comment: @JörgBeyer why would you say that?

Comment: @delnan even if the classes are almost identical in any other respect?

Comment: maybe I miss something - what should the assert verify? That b is what you expect it to be? what is "p"?

Comment: @bgbg: Sure. See Liskov Substitution Principle. The property of `GeneralCase` and its subclasses, "There's a method `f` with two parameters ... which does yadda yadda yadda", does not hold for your special case. If that's not true for some special case, that special case shouldn't be a subtype. Use mixins or something if you want code reuse.

Comment: @NiklasB. Can you please elaborate a little bit more (in an answer)?  I don't quite understand your suggestion

Comment: @bgbg: This should be a comment to my answer. However, what exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be a subtype at all (cf. Liskov Substitution Principle).

There's a property of `GeneralCase`, namely:

> There's a method `f` with two parameters ... which does yadda yadda yadda

This property should hold for all subtypes of `GeneralCase` (or going duck-typed, anything that should quack like a `GeneralCase` regardless of class relationships). If it doesn't hold, all code handling such objects would have to be aware of it and code around it. That's an unacceptable burden, and largely unnecessary.

If that property isn't true for some special case, that special case shouldn't be a subtype. It may be highly related, but either you need a more general `GeneralCase` or it's not really a special case of `GeneralCase`.

If you want code reuse, use mixins. If there's code that can operate on both `GeneralCase` and `SpecialCase` (e.g. because it doesn't use that method), you can define a more general interface that doesn't include that method (probably implicitly, we don't need no `interface` keyword) and thus steers clear of the aforementioned trouble.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class SpecialCase2(GeneralCase):
    def f(self, a, b):
        GeneralCase.f(self, a, PREDEFINED_VALUE)
```

This way the special case2 does not use b at all, and interface remains the same.

Comment: Actually this is a very bad solution. If users have the possibility to pass arguments to the function, they have the right to assume that the arguments affect function behavior.

Comment: Then override the function with new signature, but some people didn't like this solution (see above)